# WPF published application crashing when changing theme

Tags: wpf, themes, mahapps.metro

The application is working fine when i run it from Visual Studio but if i run my application when its published it crashes. This is the first application i have published so i dont know where to start.

I have 2 combo boxes that let you choose the theme color of the application as soon as i choose one it crashes.

This is using Mahapps Metro

The combobox's item source is a metro thememanager

```
ItemsSource="{x:Static metro:ThemeManager.Accents}"
```

This is the Selection Changed code

```
        private void ColorsSelectorOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        var selectedColor = this.ColorsSelector.SelectedItem as KeyValuePair<string, Color>?;
        if (selectedColor.HasValue)
        {
            var theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);

            ThemeManagerHelper.CreateAppStyleBy(selectedColor.Value.Value, true);
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Activate();
        }
```

When creating a runtime accent resource dictionary:
[image: runtime accent resource dictionary]

Comment: Did you check event log for any unhandledexceptions?

Comment: you have missing files, check your deploy folder against the bin one from visual

Comment: @GCamel I have added a screenshot of the difference in folders, im not sure what im looking for.

Comment: @DipenShah Yes there is a UnhandledException, had to google to find where this was stored haha. I have attached a screenshot of the log. It still isnt obvious where it crashed though ?

Comment: @Zevulos It seems the exception was thrown from SettingsView.ColorsSelectorOnSelectionChanged event handler. You should check for null values in there.

Comment: @DipenShah I cant see it being able to get Nul values but i am fairly new to this, it seems to be coming from when the selection is changed, i cant figure out why it works in runtime but not as a published app

Comment: @Zevulos Can you run your application in `Release` mode and check if any exception is thrown?

Comment: @DipenShah There are no Exceptions in Event Viewer but in the debug window it complains a lot saying 

`"System.Windows.ResourceDictionary warning 9:Resource not found;   ResourceKey='IdealForegroundColorBrush'"`  
It also complains about  
`Resourcekey='AccentSelectedColorBrush'`

Comment: @Zevulos Are you sure your resource dictionary contains resources with key IdealForegroundColorBrush and IdealForegroundColorBrush?

Comment: @DipenShah When i choose an item it then runs creates a run time accent resource dictionary. I have uploaded a picture of the code